# Как реализовать также для сенсорного ввода jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, touch-event

Есть код он работает там где есть мышка.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CC</title>
  <style>
    .block1 {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50px;
      top: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: blue;
      cursor: grab;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="block1" id="circle">
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var div = document.getElementById('circle');
  var listener = function(e) {
    div.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
  };
  $('#circle').on('mousedown', function() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', listener);
  })
  $('*').on('mouseup', function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', listener);
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Как реализовать также для Touch - устройств без использования библиотек и плагинов и без тега canvas?

Comment: Я пробовал в Вашем примере использовать тачпад ноутбука - все работает.  Чего хотите добиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так же добавляешь обработчики событий, только для мобильных устройств - touchstart, touchmove, touchend

Comment: тоже не работает.     var div = document.getElementById('circle');
      var listener = function(e) {
      div.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
      };
      $('#circle').on('touchstart', function(){
      document.addEventListener('touchmove', listener);
      })
      $('*').on('touchend', function(){
      document.removeEventListener('touchmove', listener);
      });

Comment: Да, забыл написать. Для событий тачпада e.pageX напрямую не работает. Для них есть массивы touches, targetTouches, changedTouches и уже в них можно брать такие свойства, как pageX. Примеры можно посмотреть тут: [ссылка](https://youon.ru/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0/touch-sobytiya-na-javascript-multitach-realizatsiya)

Comment: Спасибо! Но можете показать код как должно работать?

Comment: `var div = document.getElementById('circle');
  var listener = function(e) {
    var pageX = e.pageX;

    //если пустой pageX -  это событие тачпада
    if(!pageX){
        pageX=e.touches[0].pageX;
    }
    div.style.left = pageX+"px";
  };
  $('#circle').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', listener);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', listener);
  })
  $('*').on('mouseup touchend', function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', listener);
    document.removeEventListener('touchmove', listener);
  });`

Comment: Ну код несильно меняется. Примерно так (если я так понял задачу)

Comment: Только уж совет - `$('*')` заменить на `$(document.body)`. Событие и так всплывет до body (если не использовать stopPropagation), а вот `$('*')` - не надо так)

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает!